# How to use functions from another Julia file?

Tags: function, julia

Is it possible to call only the functions needed from another Julia script? If so, how?

When I use the `include`, the whole script is executed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either just create a script that defines the functions without doing anything else and `include` it, or you can [create your own package](https://julialang.github.io/Pkg.jl/latest/creating-packages/). The latter is pretty involved, but the basic steps are:

```
julia> ]generate MyPackage
```

or `pkg> generate MyPackage`, the `]` gets you into the package manager in the REPL. This creates the files you will need in the current directory, including a file at `./MyPackage/src/MyPackage.jl`. Add your functions to this file:

```
module MyPackage

greet() = println("Hello!")

end  # module
```

And finally include it by activating the current environment with the package manager and then including:

```
julia> ]activate .
julia> import MyPackage  # or using MyPackage
julia> MyPackage.greet()
"Hello!"
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this outside the REPL? Akin to a python package manager, `conda activate my-env && python main.py` or `poetry run main.py`?