# How include a file module in Julia 1.7?

Tags: julia

My goal is: in Julia 1.7 on Mac with M1 processor I would include a module file with many functions inside.

I've tried to follow this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57415559/how-to-use-functions-from-another-julia-file/57416163#57416163) to generate my own package
but it's generated an error.

I followed the answer but when i try importing MyPackage, Julia says: ArgumentError: Package MyPackage not found in current path.

With `pwd()` current path is Users/myname and in this folder MyPackage exists.

With command "import MyPackage" where i can see default folder for packages import ?

Where I get wrong ?

Sorry for my English.

Comment: See also my tutorial : https://syl1.gitbook.io/julia-language-a-concise-tutorial/language-core/11-developing-julia-packages There is a difference between `import x` and `import .x`

Answer (score 2):

I know two options here. Suppose I generated a package with the following file structure

```
MyPackage/
  src/
    MyPackage.jl
  Project.toml
```

and `MyPackage.jl` is

```
module MyPackage

export greet

greet() = print("Hello World!")

end # module
```

Then there are two options, I know

1. Including of **module** `MyPackage`;
2. Embedding of **package** `MyPackage` into Julia's ecosystem.

Suppose, that pwd is `MyPackage/`

**First option** is

```
julia> include("src/MyPackage.jl")
Main.MyPackage

julia> using .MyPackage

julia> greet()
Hello World!
```

Notice the [dot](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/modules/#Submodules-and-relative-paths) in `using` statement.

**Second option**

Start Julia REPL and enter pkg mode, then

```
(@v1.6) pkg> dev MyPackage/
   Resolving package versions...
    Updating `~/.julia/environments/v1.6/Project.toml`
  [88e94d31] + MyPackage v0.1.0 `foo/bar/MyPackage`
    Updating `~/.julia/environments/v1.6/Manifest.toml`
  [88e94d31] + MyPackage v0.1.0 `foo/bar/MyPackage`

(@v1.6) pkg> st
      Status `~/.julia/environments/v1.6/Project.toml`
  [6e4b80f9] BenchmarkTools v1.3.1
  [0772a1fa] CubicEoS v0.2.0
  ..........
  [88e94d31] MyPackage v0.1.0 `foo/bar/MyPackage`
  ..........
  [09ab397b] StructArrays v0.6.5
  [a759f4b9] TimerOutputs v0.5.15
```

`st` command says that `MyPackage` became available in default environment.

Then you should be able to `import`/`using` the package. For the first time you should see precompiling message.

```
julia> using MyPackage
[ Info: Precompiling MyPackage [88e94d31-ecaf-41ca-ae10-053d89a189ff]

julia> greet()
Hello World!
```

P.S. The best place for local packages is `.julia/dev/`.